# Yet another Ansible iteration

Tags: ansible

I always struggle with iterations in Ansible and this time is no different.

Anyway, I have a  custom fact being returned as a list of dictionaries `my_list` which I need to iterate to build a new variables named after the `key = 'name'`

```
[localhost] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "my_list": [
            {
                "name": "asd-ASX030-vc-0",  
                "key_2": [
                    "A", 
                    "B"
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "name": "asd-ASX030-vc-1", 
                "key_2": [
                    "C", 
                    "D"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
...
}
```

I can run a single list index.

```
  tasks:
    - set_fact: set_fact: {"{{item[1]['name'].split('-')[2:] | join('_')}}":"{{item[1]['key_2']}}"}
      loop: "{{ my_list }}"
```

What I'm after is.

```
vc_0 = ["A", "B"]
vc_1 = ["C", "D"]
```

Simple:

```
set_fact: {"{{item['name'].split('-')[2:] | `enter code here`join('_')}}":"{{item['key_2']}}"}
loop: "{{ my_list }}"
```

Doesn't work: 
`"The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'key_2'`

I would like to avoid hard coding list indexes, how can I do this dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this the code (without formatting) that you're looking for?

```yaml
shell> cat play.yml

- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    my_list:
      - name: "asd-ASX030-vc-0"
        key_2: ["A", "B"]
      - name: "asd-ASX030-vc-1"
        key_2: ["C", "D"]
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.name }} = {{ item.key_2 }}"
      loop: "{{ my_list }}"
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook play.yml | grep msg

msg: asd-ASX030-vc-0 = [u'A', u'B']
msg: asd-ASX030-vc-1 = [u'C', u'D']
```

Comment: I had a typo in my set_fact loop rather then `loop: "{{ my_list }}"` I had `loop: - "{{ my_list }}"` which created another list.

Answer (score 0):

I think you use Jinja expressions to construct the variables:

```
set_fact:
  var2:  {% for item in ansible_facts %}\
         {{ item.name }}\
         {% if not loop.last %},\
         {% endif %}\
         {% endfor %}
```